# Auditing @Embeddable @ElementCollection with hibernate-envers

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers, embeddable

I have en `Entity` containing an `@Embeddable @ElementCollection`. When trying to persist this I keep getting a `NonUniqueObjectException`.

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class Entity(){

    private Long entityId;

    @ElementCollection
    private Set<MyEmbeddableCollection> collections = new HashSet<MyEmbeddableCollection>();

}

@Embeddable
public class myEmbeddableCollection(){
    private String myId;
```

Looking at the log I can see that Envers doesn't include the `myId` to the envers table. Only the reference to the entity is included.

```
[HIST_Entity_collections#{revision_id=DefaultRevisionEntity(id = 3, revisionDate = 2013-sep-04 08:44:56), revisionTyp=ADD, entityId=1}]
```

I am using hibernate-envers 4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.
Does anybody have any solution or explanation to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in Hibernate, see [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6005), that looks like your problem.

Here is a workaround:

```
public class FixedDefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy extends DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy {
    @Override
    public String propertyToColumnName(String propertyName) {
        return super.propertyToColumnName(propertyName.replace(".collection&&element.", "."));
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to put `<property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="com.your.package.FixedDefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy"/>` in your persistence.xml file.